# I need a topic sentence for a paragraph about difficulties while in school, but dont know how to start it

Tags: word-choice

This is my topic sentence but not sure if it's grammatically correct or if there's a different word choice.

> Not being familiar with the English language was difficult for me while attending grade school.

Comment: This is a proofreading question which is off topic on EL&U. Please identify where you think the problem lies in your sentence. (If indeed there is one!) Moreover you then ask users whether you should add information about your family's mother tongue. There is no "right" answer to these type of questions, you will only provoke conflicting opinions, there will be those who argue "yes", those who will reply "perhaps" and those who will say "never".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not being familiar with the English language was difficult for me
>   while attending grade school.

It is *grammatically* correct, but it does not make any sense.  Not being familiar with things is not difficult; it is the easiest thing in the world!  I am not familiar with German, with the Peloponnesian War, with string theory, and being unfamiliar with them has not taken up a single moment of my precious time.  Never have I longed to go outside and play but was constrained to stay at my desk and *not* study, for example, entomology.

But, as you have found out, not being familiar with English can make other things difficult.

Perhaps you mean

> My unfamiliarity with the English language made grade school difficult for me.

Comment: Thanks! If I add "my parents" will it still make sense?  My parents' unfamiliarity with the English language made grade school difficult for me.

Comment: @Anel Why not change it to "our unfamiliarity with English..." and then expand from there?

Comment: How about "Unfamiliarity with the English language, on the part of my parents and myself, made grade school difficult for me."

Answer (score 1):

Old trick: just start writing. If you don't have the first sentence or paragraph ready yet, start where you can. It'll be easier to come back and edit to fill in the gap than to start from a blank piece of paper.

However, that's a fine topic sentence.

Comment: Thank you, I need to point out that my parents also not knowing the language made it difficult as well. maybe... My parents being unfamiliar with the English language made it difficult for me when I attended grade school.

Comment: "... in our household"?